# vscode makefile error: make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found. Stop

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, makefile

I have a folder under .vscode with the main.cpp, Example.cpp, Example.h and Makefile. However, when I type make into the terminal, it says "make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop."

Here is my tasks.json:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: cpp.exe build active file",
            "command": "C:\\MinGW\\bin\\cpp.exe",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": "build",
            "detail": "compiler: C:\\MinGW\\bin\\cpp.exe"
        },
        {
            "type": "shell",
            "label": "build",
            "command": "make",
            "args": [],
            "problemMatcher": []
        },
        {
            "type": "shell",
            "label": "clean",
            "command": "make",
            "args": ["clean"],
            "problemMatcher": []
        }
    ]
}
```

And the makefile:

```
example.out: main.o Example.o
    g++ main.o Example.o example.out

main.o: main.cpp Example.h 
    g++ -c main.cpp -o main.o

Example.o: Example.cpp Example.h
    g++ -c Example.cpp -o Example.o 

clean:
    rm *.o *.out
```

May I know what went wrong? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why are your sources and makefile in `.vscode`? It's supposed to contain only vsc-specific config.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat ahh I see I have moved them out of the folder! Sorry I am new to programming so I had no idea that the .vscode folder was only for vsc-specific config. But how do I solve the makefile not found error though? Thanks so much!

Comment: You're saying you type `make` into the terminal. But you're also showing us `tasks.json` with `make` commands in it? So do you type it manually, or do you run a task?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Sorry for not making myself clear, I meant i typed it manually into the terminal. I just tried runnng a task and it doesnt work as well.

Comment: Is the directory where you run `make` the same directory where `Makefile` is located? Try running `ls` instead of `make` to check the directory contents...